# Why can't I display JUST the date (date, month, and year without time)?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have some code, that is doing pretty much all i need it to do. Its calculating 3 days in the future, excluding dates, and then displaying my "estimated dispatch date"

The date, however displays in full date and time, instead of just date.
**Day Month Date Year 12:02:57 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)**

Can anyone help with the code below, so that it excludes local time and only displays the future date, excluding weekend, 
**DD/MM/YYYY** 
or, in the below format;
**Monday 20th June**

Thanks in advance!

```
function addDates(startDate,noOfDaysToAdd){
var count = 0;
while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
   //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
   count++;
}
}
return startDate;
}
var today = new Date();
var daysToAdd = 3;
document.write ('Estimated Dispatch Date: ' + addDates(today,daysToAdd));
```

Comment: Is that JavaScript? I suggest you add a tag for programming language better to attract those who know to your question. I also recommend nicer code indentation.

Comment: See [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`toDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) method to display just the date portion of your `Date` object, but you will need to use a few other methods for full control over the format of your date string...

You can display just the date, month and year parts of your local date and time with a few extra lines of code using the [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), and [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) methods to help with the formatting. You could try passing specific formatting parameters to [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), but this may display different results in different browsers. For example, the code below outputs a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy in Chrome but that output is not guaranteed across browsers.

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'})
```

Not sure I am following how you want to handle weekend dates, so the below handles the date formatting that you want in the `formatDate` function separately from the `addDays` function where it just handles weekend dates by rolling the date forward to a Monday if the initially calculated date lands on a Saturday or Sunday.

```js
// format input date to dd/mm/yyyy
const formatDate = (date) => {
  const d = date.getDate(); // day of the month
  const m = date.getMonth(); // month index from 0 (Jan) to 11 (Dec)
  const yyyy = date.getFullYear(); // 4 digit year
  const dd = (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d; // format date to 2 digit
  const mm = (m + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') + (m + 1); // convert index to month and format 2 digit
  return `${dd}/${mm}/${yyyy}`;
};

// add input days to today and adjust for weekend output
const addDays = (today, days) => {
  const now = today.getTime() // now in UTC milliseconds
  const ms = 24 * 60 * 60000; // milliseconds in one day
  const date = new Date((days * ms) + now); // today plus input days
  const day = date.getDay(); // weekday index from 0 (Sun) to 6 (Sat)
  // adjust weekend results to next weekday
  if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
    let adj = day === 0 ? 1 : 2;
    return new Date(((days + adj) * ms) + now);
  }
  
  return date;
};

document.write('Estimated Dispatch Date: ' + formatDate(addDays(new Date(), 3)));
```